# Is there an idiom for a situation in which you get all the closed windows of your mind open?

Tags: idioms, spoken-english, idiomatic-language

I am stuck to express my feelings. I watched a video about business ideas and the speaker presented it so beautifully that I got so energized and it opened up so many new ideas to me. I am looking for an idiom to express all the feelings in one sentence.

My native language is Urdu/Hindi and we have an idiom for it. "14 tabaq roshan ho jana". If somebody knows here Urdu/Hindi, s/he could read it.

Comment: Not an idiom but can express the state you went in, which is "inspiration". So you can say: "I've got inspired by that video".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I can think of is “it opened up my mind to (many) new ideas (or possibilities).” If something opens up your mind *to* something else, that something makes you aware of that something else that you may not have known about or thought much about before.

Comment: I realize now that in your original question you said it opened up many new ideas to you- this is a very similar phrase, so maybe you’re already aware you can say this.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right but I asked for an idiom in question can I accept this answer ?

Comment: I mean, if you want! Merriam-Webster considers “to open one’s mind” to be an idiom, if that matters to you: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/open%20one's%20mind

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

There are many idioms for that concept: epiphany, satori, "a lightbulb went on in my mind," and so on.

Comment: Isn't it known for "head" not "mind"? It is an idiom after all.

Comment: @TasneemZh: It can be either. In English *head* can be a synecdoche for *mind*.

Comment: "A lightbulb went on in my head" it conveys the concept of single idea in mind.. isn't it ? I want to express feeling of so many ideas in mind..

Comment: I think the more common expression is “a lightbulb went *off* in my head”- I guess it’s like an explosive device “going off”- it really means you all of a sudden had a great idea.

Answer (score 2):

A possible descriptor for this experience would be "revelatory," as in "viewing the presentation was a **revelatory** experience."

Taken literally, it means that the presentation revealed something to you. However, the word is typically reserved for experiences of new and particularly profound understanding. This is probably because of its connection to the *Book of Revelations* in the Christian Bible, in which the writer witnesses numerous strange and wondrous things that dramatically change and deepen his understanding of God and reality.